# Name Excel sheet with several strings from list

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to name an Excel sheet with two strings contained in a list.
The desired outcome would be an Excel sheet called "2020003418181 UUID". Since the number in the list is crawled and changes everytime, I need to use this list.
This is what I tried so far:

```
sheet
['Artikelnummer:', '2020003418181', 'UUID']


path = r"C:\Users\...\Desktop\export_dataframe.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
     lca_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet[1, 2], index = False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Unfortunately, I am always getting this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-cdb115f1f726> in <module>
      4 #     UUID.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='UUID', index = False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
      5 with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
----> 6      lca_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet[1,2], index = False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Is there any way to solve this? If I only use "sheet_name=sheet[1]" it works.
As a python newbie, I welcome any hints.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that in

```
sheet[1,2]
```

the part

```
1,2
```

is a `tuple`, but you need to provide integers or a slice.

A slice is an easy way to do this

```
sheet[1:3]
```

To make this into a worksheet name

```
sheetname = ' '.join(sheet[1:3])
```